# How a can be decoded as 61 and b as 62...?

Tags: c, encoding

I'm trying to stack overflow of one C program. But I'm confused by encoding or decoding algorithms.

I used ollydbg to observe registers. I tried entering "a" 28 times. And it should insert the last "a" in the EIP register because of strcopy cmd used.

When the last "a" is flowed to EIP it reads as `61`.

According to ASCII:

```
A is 65
B is 66
```

But the OS reads `a` as `61`.

What is this encoding? I'm very new to encoding.

Comment: There is no cryptography here.What are you even talking about?You need to add more details?What gdb commands you used to look at the stack?O.S read A as 61?What does anything you have written even means?

Comment: Edited. See Is this enough to explain a problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with security, as you found out. It's just a bin/hex/dec encoding representation. It really doesn't matter that you ultimately want to create an overflow condition. This question is simply about how different characters are encoded. You also need to keep straight that `A` and `a` are different characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy explanation for this:

Indeed, `'A'` is 65 in ASCII, but that is in decimal, in hex it is 0x41.

According to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), lowercase `'a'` letter has decimal code 97, which is written in hex as 0x61, and that is the value you observe.